# STM32F103C8T6 input pull-up issue

Tags: stm32, arduino-ide

PA0, PA1 and PA2 are defined as inputs with pull-ups enabled, as per below code, but when I push the button, the LED on PC13 turns off instead of being turned on.

What could be wrong? I am using STM32 Core for Arduino.

```c
    bool START = 0, STOP = 0, RESET1 = 0;

    void buttons()
    {
        START = digitalRead(PA0); //START BUTTON
        STOP = digitalRead(PA1); //STOP BUTTON
        RESET1 = digitalRead(PA2); // RESET BUTTON
    }
    
    void setup(void) {
        pinMode(PC13, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(PA0, INPUT_PULLUP);
        pinMode(PA1, INPUT_PULLUP);
        pinMode(PA2, INPUT_PULLUP);
    }
            
    void loop(void) {
        buttons();
   
        if(STOP == 0)
        {
            digitalWrite(PC13, HIGH);
        }
        else
            digitalWrite(PC13, LOW);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It depends how the LED is wired up. (You'd need to look at the schematic.) But it's not unusual to have an LED that lights up when you drive a signal low, and vice-versa. But to be clear, it's probably not a problem with the buttons. It's how you are driving the LED.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are saying that the LED on PC13 is mostly on, but when you push the `STOP` button, it turns off?

This can easily be explained if the LED is wired up so that its anode it connected to positive voltage (e.g. 3.3V in many circuits these days), and the cathode is connected to PC13.

If you drive PC13 high (when the button is pressed), the voltage at the anode and cathode will both be high, and no current will flow. The LED will be off.

When you drive PC13 low (when the button is not pressed), the voltage at the cathode will be 0V, and a current will flow through the LED. The STM32 is acting as a current sink, and the LED will be on.

You've maybe got the idea in your mind that you have to drive a signal high to turn on an LED. That would be true if the LED had its cathode connected to 0V, and the anode connected to PC13, in which case the STM32 would be acting a current source.

But it can be done either way, neither is particularly better.

If this is indeed how your board is wired up, the solution is simple - drive PC13 low when you want the LED to be on, and drive it high when you want it to be off:

```c
        if(STOP == 0)
        {
          digitalWrite(PC13, LOW);
        }
        else
          digitalWrite(PC13, HIGH);
        }
```